# Cleaning git repo of large files

Tags: git, bitbucket, bfg-repo-cleaner

I committed over 600 large(ish) jpgs to my git repo and can now see the error of my way. I have used the BFG to remove them and my local repository no longer shows them. My local git GUI doesn't show them. If I check the size of the repo in Finder then it shows 119Mb.

But...
The repo size on BitBucket still shows 1.6Gb. If I choose to download the repo from BB then I get a 119Mb file downloaded.
I also ran the following command:

`while read -r largefile; do     echo $largefile | awk '{printf "%s %s ", $1, $3 ; system("git rev-list --all --objects | grep " $1 " | cut -d \" \" -f 2-")}'; done <<< "$(git rev-list --all --objects | awk '{print $1}' | git cat-file --batch-check | sort -k3nr | head -n 20)"`

and that shows a whole load of large files that I thought had been cleared out by BFG.

Any ideas how I can resolve it.  I'm not fully versed with Git so please go easy on me! :-)

Answer (score 0):

You do not really need to worry about it. Make sure that there are no branches/tags in the remote which still have those files somewhere in their reference. If that is so, then their garbage collector should clean them up after some time.

I am not that familiar with BitBucket - try to find out if you can somehow force it to do a GC pass on their side, maybe that fixes the problem already.